# Kotlin Error : None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied

Tags: android, kotlin

Following is compilation error

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: 
public final operator fun div(other: Byte): Int defined in kotlin.Int
public final operator fun div(other: Double): Double defined in kotlin.Int
public final operator fun div(other: Float): Float defined in kotlin.Int
public final operator fun div(other: Int): Int defined in kotlin.Int
public final operator fun div(other: Long): Long defined in kotlin.Int
public final operator fun div(other: Short): Int defined in kotlin.Int
```

I tried with the count-down timer in my activity below is my code. I got the error mark on the division operator

```
mTimerTextview.setText(millisUntilFinished.toInt()  / 1000.toString() + "s")
```

Full code

```
startQuizButton.setOnClickListener {
            constraintChild.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            startQuizButton.visibility = View.GONE
            score = 0
            totalAttempt = 0
            mStatusTextview.text = "0/0"
            newQuestion()
            countDownTimer = object : CountDownTimer(30100, 1000) {
                override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                    mTimerTextview.setText(millisUntilFinished.toInt()  / 1000.toString() + "s")
                }
```

Comment: You're trying to divide an integer and a string here, what would you expect this to do? For example what would you expect `4/"s"` to give you? Maybe you meant `(millisUntilFinished.toInt()  / 1000).toString()`?

Comment: I need here 30s. it will be a countdown time. if the 30s finish then the activity will be closed automatically

Comment: So you should be dividing your milliseconds by 1000 *before* converting it to a string, like I said in my comment.

Answer (score 0):

I just replace this:

```
val one = millisUntilFinished.toInt()
                    val two = 1000
                    mTimerTextview.text = ((one / two).toString() + "s")
```